# What's causing the read access violation/overflow?

Tags: c, recursion, overflow

I'm trying to write a program that sorts an array of size N via a selections sort and then conducts a binary search for a random number in that array and displays the index in which that number is present. I noticed that without my binary search function I begin to get a stack overflow when N is greater than 1e5 and when I try to run the binary search I run into the error "read access violation". I would greatly appreciate any help on this especially considering my N is supposed to be 1e6.

```
   #define N 10
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

//function prototypes
void selectionSort(int array[], size_t length);
void swap(int* elementPtr, int* element2Ptr);
void printPass(int array[], size_t length, unsigned int pass, size_t index);
size_t binarySearch(const int b[], int searchKey, size_t low, size_t high);

unsigned long long int counter = 0;
unsigned long long int counter2 = 0;
long long unsigned int counter3 = 0;


int main(void) {
    int array[N];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        array[i] = rand() % 90 + 10; // give each element a value
    }

    /*
    puts("Unsorted array:");

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) { //print the array
        printf("%d  ", array[i]);
    }
    puts("{\n");
    */

    selectionSort(array, N);

    /*
    puts("Sorted array:");

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) { //print the array
        printf("%d  ", array[i]);
    }
    */

    printf("\nTotal amount of comparisons: %d\n", counter);
    printf("Total amount of swaps: %d", counter2);

    int value = rand() % N + 1;
    int index = binarySearch(array, value, 0, N);
    printf("\nThe amount of times the value was compared was: %d\n", counter3);
    if (index != -1) {
        printf("%d was first found on index %d\n", value, index);
    }
    else printf("%d was not found on the array\n", value);

}


void selectionSort(int array[], size_t length) {
    //loop over length - 1 elements
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
        size_t smallest = i; //first index of remaining array
        //loop to find index of smallest element
        for (size_t j = i + 1; j < length; j++) {
            counter++;
            if (array[j] < array[smallest]) {
                smallest = j;
            }
        }
        swap(array + i, array + smallest); //swap smallest element
        //printPass(array, length, i + 1, smallest); //output pass
    }
}

//function that swaps two elements in the array
void swap(int* elementPtr,int* element2Ptr)
{
    counter2++;
    int temp;
    temp = *elementPtr;
    *elementPtr = *element2Ptr;
    *element2Ptr = temp;

}

//function that prints a pass of the algorithm
void printPass(int array[], size_t length, unsigned int pass, size_t index) {
    printf("After pass %2d: ", pass);

    //output elements till selected item
    for (size_t i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
    printf("%d ", array[index]); //indicate swap

    //finish outputting array
    for (size_t i = index + 1; i < length; i++) {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
    printf("%s", "\n               "); //for alignment

    //indicate amount of array that is sorted
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < pass; i++) {
        printf("%s", "-- ");
    }
    puts(""); //add newline
}

size_t binarySearch(const int b[], int searchKey, size_t low, size_t high) {
    counter3++;
    if (low > high) {
        return -1;
    }
    size_t middle = (low + high) / 2;

    if (searchKey == b[middle]) {
        return middle;
    }

    else if (searchKey < b[middle]) {
        return binarySearch(b, searchKey, low, middle - 1);
    }

    else {
        return binarySearch(b, searchKey, middle + 1, high);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you enabled compiler warnings, run with address-sanitizer and/or under Valgrind?

Comment: @kaylum What are you on about? The only recursive function I see here is `binarySearch()`. Completely aside from that function being **tail-recursive**, which will make it consume constant stack space on any non-braindead compiler, it's also inherently only going to take logarithmic space at worst (on said braindead compiler). Assuming you have a tight 2MiB of stack, and each activation frame takes an egregious 64 bytes, you can select from a tiny `pow(2, 32768)` elements. I can *definitely* see your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `N` as big as `1e5` or `1e6`, you can't afford allocating it on stack. The size of an `int` is 4 bytes and so you'll consume `4e5` bytes from stack just for your array.

You will need to dynamically allocate the array and instead of

```c
    int array[N];
```

you should have

```c
    int *array = malloc(sizeof(int) * N);
```

and after you are done with everything, don't forget to

```c
    free(array);
```

Now you should have enough space on stack for the recursive binary search.

**UPDATE:**

After I've run the code myself, indeed, the `binarySearch` function always yields segmentation fault. The problem is the type of the parameters, namely `size_t`. There are cases where `high` argument from the `binarySearch` function becomes `-1`. But because the `size_t` is an unsigned type, you have an integer underflow, thus `high` will become maxint. So your condition `if (low > high)` would never become true. You'll have to change the types of `low` and `high` to a signed integer to have the function working.

Still, I suggest going for the dynamic allocation, even though your stack might cope with that.

Comment: "Now you should have enough space on stack for the recursive binary search". And how do you know that?  Even with that dynamic allocation there is still no guarantee that there is enough stack for N=1e5 let alone N=1e6.

Comment: True that, but given the binary search is implemented correctly, `log(1e6)` calls should not overflow it.

Comment: You are on the right track, but the solution is not right. The real problem is that `high` itself does not belong to the range, so (a) the recursion shall be terminated at `low == high` - it is an empty range, and (b) the first recursive call should be passed `middle` rather than `middle - 1`.

Comment: @user58697 It depends how you interpret `high`. If the range does not include `high`, then yes, your statement is true. Otherwise, the code is correct. But your observation is right, as I see the calling statement is with `N`, not `N - 1`.

Comment: The range does _not_ include `high`. Look at the initial invocation `binarySearch(array, value, 0, N);` Here `high` is `N`, and is definitely outside of the range.

Comment: I've seen that afterwards, it's a mixture of both approaches. Both are correct, but they definitely don't work mixed up.

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot as well with the mention of how the range was not correct as I intended it to be N-1 but forgot altogether. In addition, noticing how I passed my values also affected it as I changed the way I would send them to the swap function. Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Even outside of the great answer that was posted, I am seeing other problems with this code.  I have issues running it with N = 2, N =5, and N = 10.

I believe you have some problems with passing the variables into your binary search function.  I think that you are passing incorrect values that are overflowing and causing all sorts of memory nightmares. This is causing your read access violations.

Do your small cases function appropriately?  Despite the suggestions to minimize your footprint.  I would double check simple cases are functioning.

[image: N=2 Run Results]

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. It's an integer underflow. high becomes -1, but size_t is unsigned. I've edited my answer as well. Nice job spotting that!

Comment: Exactly! I don't have the reputation to comment your answer.  But yes you explained it perfectly.  I am running a test of 1e6 as we speak.  Ill throw the result on here just so he can see (even with the memory hungry algorithm) that it works.  As somewhat expected, this wont make it to 1e6 as is.  Optimize it and give it another shot with the fix Vlad mentioned.